# How to detect (java code) "box type" googleTV or googleTV with a built in display ("TV type")

Tags: android, google-tv

Is there a way to detect this in my Android Application code ?
I want to differentiate "Box type" (e.g. NSZGS7, without display attached) and built-into-TV type (NSXGT1, with display) googleTV devices. Is there a standard system property or feature flag that I can use for this differentiation ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a super elegant way to detect if a device has a display or if it's a box. But you can use android.os.Build to detect Manufacturer/Device/Model etc and differentiate based on the system properties.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

Here are the system properties for most of the currently available GTV devices:

```
                    MANUFACTURER  DEVICE           MODEL           
Sony NSX-GT1(TV)    Sony          asura            Internet TV     
Sony NSZ-GT1(BD)    Sony          eagle            Internet TV Box 
Sony NSZ-GS7(Box)   Sony          NSZGS7           NSZ-GS7/GX70    
Sony NSZ-GU1(Stick) Sony          NSZGU1           NSZ-GU1    
Logitech Revue(Box) logitech      ka               Revue 
Netgear GTV100(Box) Netgear       NeoTV            GTV100          
Hisense Pulse(Box)  hisense       hisense_gx1200v  hisense_gx1200v 
Vizio Costar (Box)  VIZIO         VAP430           VAP430          
LG G2(TV)           lge           cosmo            LG Google TV
```

Hope this helps! -Tonni from Sony

Comment: Yes, I am using the "DEVICE" property right now - I have posted the code I am using. As you can see the code I have now will need to be updated in the future when new TV type devices are released. I wish there was a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I am using for now. It is not future proof, meaning this code will need to be updated as new TV type GoogleTV devices are released. However, this code gets the job done for now.

```
boolean is_gtv_device_type_tv(){
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("com.google.android.tv")) {
        if(android.os.Build.DEVICE != null) {
            if(android.os.Build.DEVICE.equalsIgnoreCase("asura"))
                return true;
            if(android.os.Build.DEVICE.equalsIgnoreCase("cosmo"))
                return true;
        }

        // All other google tv devices are buddy boxes!! :)
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for `ro.hdmi.device_type` in "device properties" (For HDMI sink devices, like panel TVs it's "0", for HDMI source devices, like Over the Top (OTT) boxes it's "4").

Using ABD:

```
adb shell getprop ro.hdmi.device_type
```

Programmatically:

```
public static String getDeviceType() {
    switch (System.getProperty("ro.hdmi.device_type")){
        case "0":
            return "TV";
        case "4":
            return "BOX";
        default:
            return "UNKNOWN";
    }
}
```